# Get frontmost folder path as variable - applescript in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables, applescript

Im traying get variable from applescript to python
Here is my script:

```
import subprocess

def save_path():
    cmd = """
        tell application "Finder"
        set currentPath to POSIX path of ((get insertion location) as alias)
        end tell
"""
    result = subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', cmd], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout

print(save_path())
```

Why is it not working....

Comment: What does "frontmost folder" mean? Consider the description of `insertion location`: *the container in which a new folder would appear if “New Folder” was selected*

Comment: I get a result, so what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: How can I get variable currentPath? FrontMost is the current open mac is Finder window. Thank You

Comment: Works perfectly OMM (Python 3.9.5, 10.14.6). I assume you’ve already checked it’s running in Python 3.5 or later, which is when `subprocess.run()` was added, not Python 2. The only change I would make is to add `encoding='utf8'` to the `run()` call, since `osascript returns strings in UTF8 encoding. (`set currentPath to` is also redundant and can be omitted, as AS returns the result of the last expression evaluated, which is the right side of the `set…to`.) If you’re still stuck, post your error message and any other diagnostic information so folk here can troubleshoot.